# Fetching data from database into angular datatable

Tags: angular

I have some data stored in my database which i want to fetch and place in my angular datatable, but it doesn't work out and i can't find the reason why. Although, the instances i create in the constructor show up in my angular table, but i want to be able to request the stored data in my database into my angular datatable. Thanks!

customer.ts file

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpService} from "./Client_Service";
import {Response} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'client',
  templateUrl:'client_table.html',
  providers:[HttpService]


})

  export class ClientComponent{

  welcome: string;
  clients: [{
     Name: string,
     Email: string,
     Company: string

  }];

  constructor(){
    this.welcome = "Customer Listing"
    this.clients = [{
      Name: "John Jan",
      Email:"example.com",
      Company: "Metabo"
    }

    ]

  };



   customers:Customer[];

   constructor(private httpService: HttpService){}

  ngOnInit(){


    this.httpService.getCustomer()
      .subscribe(
        (data: Response ) => console.log(data.json())
      );

  }




}
```

// My angular datatable

```
<h1>{{welcome}}</h1>
<table class="table">

  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th> Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Company</th>



 </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let client of clients; let i = index">
      <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
      <td>{{client.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{client.Email}}</td>
      <td>{{client.Company}}</td>

    </tr>


</table>
```

// Http service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Response, Http} from '@angular/http';
  import {DataListModule} from 'primeng/primeng';


@Injectable()

 export class HttpService{

  constructor(private http:Http){

  }

   getCustomer(){
     //using get request
     return this.http.get('http://localhost:9000/api/crm_api/v1/customers')
       .map((response: Response) => response.json())



   }





}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

```
 this.httpService.getCustomer()
      .subscribe(
        (data: Response ) => console.log(data.json())
      );
```

is working, all you have to do is:

```
 this.httpService.getCustomer()
      .subscribe(
        (data: Response ) => {
          console.log(data.json())
          this.clients = data;
       }
      );
```

Comment: I keep getting this error : Type 'Response is not assignable to type '[{first_name: string; last _name : string  ...

Comment: remove the `Response` give it a type interface or just do like : `(data: any) => {` instead of `(data: Response ) => {`

Comment: thank you very much..i see the response in the console now. Will check how to show them on the table too. Thanks a lot

Comment: @echonax It was me, I just realized that now. Sorry man, I didn't mean it :D Could you edit your post, and I'll fix it ;)